# Hide current flag from language selector in Magento

Tags: magento

Our shop has two store views. One is Dutch the other is English. We use the following code to show the flags to choose a view.

```
<?php if(count($this->getStores()) > 1): ?>
<div class="form-language">
        <div class="langs-wrapper">
    <?php foreach ($this->getStores() as $_lang): ?>
        <?php $selected = $_lang->getId() == $this->getCurrentStoreId() ?>
        <a class="lang-flag<?php $selected && print ' selected' ?>" href="<?php echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl() ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/flags/' . $_lang->getCode() . '.png');?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_lang->getName()) ?>">
        </a>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Now we want to hide the flag for the current language. Because you don't need to see that. How can we create this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this  hope it will do your work

```
<?php if(count($this->getStores()) > 1): ?>
<div class="form-language">
        <div class="langs-wrapper">
    <?php foreach ($this->getStores() as $_lang): ?>
        <?php $selected = $_lang->getId() == $this->getCurrentStoreId() ?>

<?php if(Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode()==$_lang->getCode()):?>
        <a class="lang-flag<?php $selected && print ' selected' ?>" href="<?php echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl() ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/flags/' . $_lang->getCode() . '.png');?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_lang->getName()) ?>">
        </a>
       <?php endif ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: When i replace the code, the complete site disappears.

Comment: i've made a little change, see in the post below. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I changed Rohit Goel's code to:

```
 <?php if(count($this->getStores()) > 1): ?>
<div class="form-language">
        <div class="langs-wrapper">
    <?php foreach ($this->getStores() as $_lang): ?>
        <?php $selected = $_lang->getId() == $this->getCurrentStoreId() ?>

<?php if(Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode() !=$_lang->getCode()):?>
        <a class="lang-flag<?php $selected && print ' selected' ?>" href="<?php echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl() ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/flags/' . $_lang->getCode() . '.png');?>" class="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_lang->getName()) ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_lang->getName()) ?>">
        </a>
       <?php endif ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

And that worked! Thanks